# JPBM 7.61.0 and LDAP

Tags: openldap, jbpm

New to JBPM and Wildfly server.  Trying to get a basic LDAP setup to work with jBPM.  I think the best example I've found is here:
https://blog.kie.org/2021/02/migrating-jbpm-images-secured-by-ldap-to-elytron.html

However that example is based on KieLoginModule integration which isn't in the build anymore, as noted by the Author.

So question, where I can find an example of LDAP integration with jBPM on the newest 7.61.0 server?

We are running this via docker, so .cli would be ideal but I can reverse engineer a working standalone.xml into .cli if need be.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This video would help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UpT92-GIxc

and You can see https://groups.google.com/g/jbpm-setup/c/Ebt8cwfh3dU

You can join JBPM google group where JBPM expert can help if you face any issue in JBPM.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this?

https://github.com/gmunozfe/integration-sample-kie-server/tree/ldap_last

I adapted the CLI scripts to work with out-of-the-box elytron.

Comment: Yes, I have.  The issue with this and most of the examples online is the server.xml has changed.  A lot of the sections modified by the CLI has been removed (or renamed/structured).  I don't enough about how these server.xml files and how security is defined to know what is relevant and what isn't.  I don't understand why there isn't a standard section for this.  Where I just have to change my server info and org structure, and maybe map groups.

Comment: @Jay I'm not sure what you mean by server.xml has changed, if you are using a jbpm docker image (jbpm-show-case, as in my example, 7.61.0.Final or latest version) cli changes are the only ones needed to set up LDAP as auth backend server.

Comment: Sorry, wrong file standalone.xml has changed.  The cli script throws errors when the sections it's looking for are not in the standalone.xml file.  Since you are using 7.61.0 as well, do you have a cli to share that works for you?

Comment: Sure, I think you didn't release that my comment pointed to a different branch. Here they are (working with 7.61.0.Final and latest): https://github.com/gmunozfe/integration-sample-kie-server/tree/ldap_last/src/test/resources/etc/ldap